# Symbol addresses in ELF

Tags: symbols, elf

I am trying to read ELF symbol table.

I am facing following discrepancy in shared libraries and can't understand the reason behind it.

For libc, using `readelf` i got following output.

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
7: 00000033c32160b0   146 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 realloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
8: 00000033c3421000     4 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   21 _dl_starting_up@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
9: 00000033c32118f0   382 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _dl_allocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
10: 00000033c3421280    40 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 _r_debug@@GLIBC_2.2.5
11: 00000033c341fdc8     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 __libc_stack_end@@GLIBC_2.2.5
12: 00000033c3215f30   252 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 __libc_memalign@@GLIBC_2.2.5
13: 00000033c3211a70   140 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _dl_deallocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
14: 00000033c3216040    52 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 calloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
15: 00000033c341fc88     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 _dl_argv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
16: 00000033c3211000   599 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _dl_mcount@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

and for my own shared library build using following commands

```
gcc -rdynamic -Wint-to-pointer-cast -g -fPIC -lpthread -c probes.c -ldl -lelf  
gcc -shared -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed,-soname,libprobes.so.1 -o libprobes.so.1 mutrace.o -ldl -lelf
```

the output was

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
.
.
.
34: 00000000000040d0    66 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 pthread_create
35: 0000000000001d72   109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 thread_local_init
36: 0000000000002b21   481 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 trylock_ret_event
37: 00000000000030c4   652 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 lock_init_event
38: 0000000000003e4d   130 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 pthread_mutex_init
39: 0000000000004668     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _fini
40: 0000000000003dd0   125 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 pthread_cond_timedwait
41: 0000000000001b03    92 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 backtrace
42: 0000000000001b5f    94 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 backtrace_symbols
43: 0000000000002ee3   481 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 unlock_ret_event
44: 0000000000004026    95 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 pthread_mutex_trylock
45: 0000000000003531   476 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 lock_destroy_event
46: 0000000000004112  1012 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 print_symtable
```

For libc the symbol values are absolute ( virtual address ) but in my library, the values are relative. **What decides this behaviour ?**

I have tried following the information from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-0690/chapter6-35166/index.html , but latter when i checked the ELF header, both the libraries had same type.

Answer (score 1):

> for my own shared library build using following commands
>
> gcc -rdynamic -Wint-to-pointer-cast -g -fPIC -lpthread -c probes.c -ldl -lelf
> gcc -shared -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed,-soname,libprobes.so.1 -o libprobes.so.1

These commands are *incorrect*. The first one is a compilation command (because of `-c` flag). The linker options (`-rdynamic`, `-lpthread`, etc.) don't belong on it.

The second command is link command, and has the wrong library order. In addition, you forgot to actually use `probes.o` that you compiled. This would be better:

```
gcc -shared -o libprobes.so.1 -Wl,-soname=libprobes.so.1 probes.o -lpthread
```

> For libc the symbol values are absolute

No, they are not. Your libc has apparently been prelinked at address `0x33c3210000` (or similar). That doesn't make the symbols absolute. You can undo prelinking (read `man prelink`) and you'll see similar "relative" addresses in `libc.so.6`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections in my command. Your explanation answered my question.